# Vue - how can i call another method from a callback?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to call the function `get_data()` once the function `save_key()` is done executing, the problem is that i get a `Cannot read property 'get_data' of undefined` error. I assume i'm getting it because the function is called from a callback. How can i solve this?

```
methods: {
    async get_data(){
        var response = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/retrieve_user_data");
            this.keys = response['data']
    },

    save_key(){
        var key_data = {'action': 'save', 'key': this.form.key}

        return axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/save_data/',
          data: key_data,
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {}
        }).then(function (response) {
            this.get_data()
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: use arrow function `}).then((response) => {`

Comment: Indeed, that worked! Can you make an answer so that i can accept it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the scope of 'this' is set to global(window) object in your callback. This can be solved by using arrow function or using a placeholder variable for this. You can try and update your save_key function like this

```
save_key(){
    const self = this;
    var key_data = {'action': 'save', 'key': this.form.key}

    return axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/save_data/',
        data: key_data,
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {}
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            self.get_data();
        })

    }
```

Comment: `const self = this;` is poor practice, one can use either an arrow function or bind(this) to the function